# Split table into new multiple tables with dynamic table name assignment

Tags: mysql, variables, split

I've a "**TableOriginal**" that I want to "split" into multiple tables, each one with the **name** of the different values than can be found on "*split*" column in "**tableOriginal**". The name, therefore, must be dynamic (maybe formed by a variable that is the result of a previous query).

**TableOriginal:**

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | split | value |
+----+-------+-------+
| 1  |   A   |  v1   |
| 2  |   A   |  v2   |
| 3  |   A   |  v3   |
| 4  |   B   |  v4   |
| 5  |   B   |  v5   |
| 6  |   B   |  v6   |
| 7  |   C   |  v7   |
| 8  |   C   |  v8   |
| 9  |   A   |  v9   |
| 10 |   B   |  v10  |
| 11 |   B   |  v11  |
| 12 |   C   |  v12  |
+----+-------+-------+
```

**TableSplit_A**

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | original_id | value |
+----+-------------+-------+
| 1  |      1      |  v1   |
| 2  |      2      |  v2   |
| 3  |      3      |  v3   |
| 4  |      9      |  v9   |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

**TableSplit_B**

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | original_id | value |
+----+-------------+-------+
| 1  |      4      |  v4   |
| 2  |      5      |  v5   |
| 3  |      6      |  v6   |
| 4  |      10     |  v10  |
| 5  |      11     |  v11  |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

**TableSplit_C**

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | original_id | value |
+----+-------------+-------+
| 1  |      7      |  v7   |
| 2  |      8      |  v8   |
| 3  |      12     |  v12  |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

## SQLFiddle:

[**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61266**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61266)

Comment: SQL Fiddle is back now.  Sorry 'bout that!

Comment: Because comments to @AbdiasSoftare are partially hidden, I post here the reason the given answer is almost there but not truly closed: I just need now to get the "A,B,C" dynamically based on `SELECT split FROM TableOriginal GROUP BY split` and use each of the returned values as a variable to be cycled (kinda "for" cycle) use with @AbdiasSoftare code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) for this. For the dynamic approach see the `TEMPTABLE` argument to the VIEW.

In the VIEW's Create query you then use alias for the column name.

In my opinion dynamics in relation should be handled in code and not in procedures on server. Anyways, here's an example:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED 
DEFINER=`user`@`yourserver` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `tableA` AS select `tableoriginal`.`id` AS `id`,
     `tableoriginal`.`split` AS `tableoriginal_A`,
     `tableoriginal`.`value` AS `value` 
from 
     `tableoriginal` 
where
     (`tableoriginal`.`split` = 'A')
```

Now you can query `TableA` as any other table (I skipped the `TEMPTABLE` in this example).

Hope this was related to what you where looking for.

Added to fiddler:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4304/1

UPDATE: (based on the comments below)

Personally I work by the STORE-NOP principle :-P use a database only to STOre-REtrieve-NOt-for-Processing (tm), so I would do it in two steps:

```
select distinct split from TableOriginal;
```

Then go through each result and inject the result in a pre-defined query (notice {0} in the string, these will be replaced later - and perhaps different in the language you're using):

```
myView = "CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `table{0}` AS select `tableoriginal`.`id` AS `id`,
     `tableoriginal`.`split` AS `tableoriginal_{0}`,
     `tableoriginal`.`value` AS `value` 
from 
     `tableoriginal` 
where
     (`tableoriginal`.`split` = '{0}')
;"
```

Then run the query for each line in result (pseudo code in VB):

```
For Each line In DBQueryResult
  cmd.ExecuteWrite(String.Format(myView, line.field("split"))
Next
```

I cannot check right now if these are valid statement, but it's meant as pseudo code so you can get the idea how you can do this in the language you are using.

You also might want to consider use a IF EXIST/DROP VIEW or a TEMPTABLE in the final query.

Comment: What I couldn't find is somewhat a "for cycle" to address to @tablename the value of each GROUP BY...

Comment: I can't see where you use group by or @tablename anywhere?

Comment: To get the a table with just one column, with the results ('A','B','C'). Wrong approach? :) Given TableOriginal I first need to extract those values and, then, use them to create table CONCAT("TableSplit_",@tablename), insert into...

Comment: I updated my answer - see if it touches upon what you looking for (I am not fully sure I understand :) am on my 20th hour and will hit the pillow)

Comment: :) thanks! Good night, I'm also on a crusade that began saturday morning (here is sunday midday).. Even so, my problem is to "split" a huge amount of data (15Gb table) into multiple, more manageable ones (it's almost impossible to query the first one). So, what I need is to create about 120 small tables, with the table name as the unique values of a single column in my huge table and put in those new tables the slice of the data that belongs to it.

Comment: Your response is almost there!!!, now I just need to get the letter "A" from a query :P

Comment: Please help me a little bit more if you can... My "crusade" hasn't finished yet :) As I said on previous comment, I just need now to get the "A,B,C" dynamically based on `SELECT split FROM TableOriginal GROUP BY split` and use each of this values as a variable for your code. Sorry the bold insistence...

Comment: @kairos I updated my answer. See if not this will do the job.